# Extracting data from html table using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<table class="softwares" border="1" cellpadding="0" width="99%">
    <thead style="background-color: #ededed">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><b>Windows</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Type</b></td>
            <td><b>Issue</b></td>
            <td><b>Restart</b></td>
            <td><b>Severity</b></td>  
            <td><b>Impact</b></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>some item</td>
            <td><a href="some website">some website</a><br></td>
            <td>Yes<br></td>
            <td>Critical<br></td>
            <td>stuff<br></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td>some item</td>
            <td><a href="some website">some website</a><br></td>
            <td>Yes<br></td>
            <td>Important<br></td>
            <td>stuff<br></td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The html page that I am trying to get the data from is a local file that I have saved onto my pc and is filled with multiple tables formatted the same as this. I'm trying to get the both the title for each of these tables, in this specific case "Windows," as well as the urls that are located in the table body. I have been trying to use beautiful soup and python to get the table titles and the websites and print them in a table with the title on the left, and the corresponding urls on the right, but I am unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all` to gather all `td` tag objects, and then apply additional logic to store the `href`s:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = soup(re.sub('\s', '', open('filename.html').read()), 'lxml')
final_results = [[i.text, i.find('a')['href']] if i.find('a') else i.text for i in s.find_all('td')]
name = final_results[0]
header = final_results[1:6]
full_results = final_results[6:]
```

Output:

```
u'Windows'
[u'Type', u'Issue', u'Restart', u'Severity', u'Impact']
[u'some item', [u'some website', 'some website'], u'Yes', u'Critical', u'stuff', u'some item', [u'some website', 'some website'], u'Yes', u'Important', u'stuff']
```

The results can be further combined to a dictionary:

```
table = [dict(zip(header, full_results[i:i+5])) for i in range(0, len(full_results), 5)]
```

Output:

```
[{u'Impact': u'stuff', u'Issue': [u'some website', 'some website'], u'Type': u'some item', u'Severity': u'Critical', u'Restart': u'Yes'}, {u'Impact': u'stuff', u'Issue': [u'some website', 'some website'], u'Type': u'some item', u'Severity': u'Important', u'Restart': u'Yes'}]
```

Comment: So I tried your code and for some reason, I end up with any empty list for final_results and as a result, an index out of bounds error. When I use get_text() the document prints all the text though but once I start using find or find_all, the lists are returned empty.

Comment: @ArjunAthreya I added a file read to the solution. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Still getting the same index out of bounds error on the name = final_results[0].

Comment: So I took at the code of the html file and it's really weirdly spaced with spaces between each character, but when the file is launched, the webpage looks totally normal. Not sure why the weird spacing is happening in html file when opened up in an editor.

Comment: @ArjunAthreya When you mention spaces, do you mean that the tags themselves are mutated? such as `< t d >`?

Comment: Yep, all the tags are mutated exactly like that. Is there some reason for this I'm unaware of?

Comment: Every character has a space between them so the a tag looks like < t d >

Comment: @ArjunAthreya Is that true for *every* character in the file, or just `html` tags?

Comment: every character in the file

Comment: @ArjunAthreya. Please see my recent edit. The code removes every instance of a `\s` and replaces it with `''`. This assumes that every "true" space will be padded with an additional `\s`, thus, regular spaces will be maintained.

Comment: So I added the edit and I'm still getting an index out of bounds error. I did s.get_text() to see the output and I still have spaces between the characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') # content variable holds the `table elements`
title = soup.select_one(".softwares thead td b").text
links = [item.a.get("href") for item in soup.select(".softwares tr td") if item.a]
print(title,links)
```

Output:

```
Windows ['some website', 'some website']
```